# "password must contain an uppercase ASCII character" with MD5 hash

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

According to [the CREATE USER docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_USER.html) passwords can be specified either as plain text or as an MD5 hash.

When I try and create a user with an MD5 hash I get:

```
Error occurred during SQL script execution

Reason:
SQL Error [500310] [42601]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: password must contain an uppercase ASCII character;
```

The only mention of this problem I can find [on the AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=230152) says:

> Your cluster has probably not been upgraded yet.
>
> The version with the MD5 password functionality is `1.0.1046` and my clusters are on `1.0.1044`.

But my cluster is on <s>`1.0.10936`</s> `1.0.11116`. Is this a known issue? How can I proceed to create my users with an MD5 hash instead of a plaintext password?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually dealt with in the docs, but it's a little bit tucked away.

> Concatenate 'md5' in front of the MD5 hash string and provide the concatenated string as the md5hash argument.
>
> `create user user1 password 'md5153c434b4b77c89e6b94f12c5393af5b';`

You must add `md5` to the start of the password for it to be treated as an MD5 hash. If you do that, then it will work.